# Does setting up Mercer Safehouse as a settlement effect anything?

Tags: fallout-4

I just completed the Railroad quest to set up Mercer Safehouse as requested by PAM, but I am hesitant to send settlers or place a recruitment beacon there. Is it okay to have settlers settle it or does its covert function mean that I should just leave it empty?

In other words, are there any reasons that I should leave Mercer Safehouse uninhabited (such as penalties or being locked out of quests) or can I go ahead and send some settlers over?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Mercer Safehouse page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mercer_Safehouse) at Nukapedia, and on my own hazy recollection, I think you can go ahead and use it like a normal settlement.

That page says that

> The location you get sent to is random, and in the event you have cleared every settlement, it will send you to one already under your control.

Kalina has pointed out that there is at least one quest related to the Mercer Safehouse: [Concierge](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Concierge). However, there's no reason to think that having other settlers there would negatively impact this quest.

Comment: It won't impact any dialogue or anything right? I'd rather keep the list of NPCs that yell at me constantly to Marcy Long.

Comment: IIRC [there is a quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Concierge), there is an old guy that wanders around the settlement after you set up the safe house that you do a side quest for called the Caretaker, but I didn't play with a beacon at Mercer so don't know having people there effects it

Comment: Good to know it's random. 'Cause the location I got is hardly more than just the one house and a very small bit of surrounding property, most of which is cluttered by non-removable stuff. ([Jamaica Plain](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jamaica_Plain)) I was wondering who in their right mind would actually want to *use* that.