# How is the location of "Mercer Safehouse" determined?

Tags: fallout-4

In dealing with the Railroad faction in Fallout 4, PAM will ask you to turn over/align a settlement with the Railroad, making it "Mercer Safehouse". What/when/how is that settlement selected?

After multiple reloads and I keep getting asked for the same settlement... of which I have no interest in aligning that one directly with the Railroad. I would have thought the random determination had been selected when being given the mission?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247387/mercer-safehouse-railroad-quest), the safe house is determined randomly, from the list of settlements you have not yet taken over. If you have unlocked all settlements, it will be a random settlement you own.

Fallout 4 has a habit of pre-determining random elements, early. If there are other settlements you are yet to unlock, it has likely just set the original settlement in, earlier than the save file you are trying to reload.

You could try reloading an older save, and see if you can trigger a different settlement. As stated in the same answer, the Mercer safe house acts like any other settlement. There is no real disadvantage to loosing any specific settlement to the Railroad, this way.

Comment: Nothing is really absolutely random. Nonetheless, the game had it fair pick of other settlements I have yet to acquire. And having tried older saves, the game still selects the same settlement. Thanks anyway

Comment: Depends on your definition of random, @Jarvis. Technically, nothing computer automated is truely random. Computers are incapable of applying random logic, so its usually automated, using the system clock, in milliseconds.

Comment: Exactly. But in regards to the original topic I was just hoping to hear from someone who has gone through the quest scripts already to enlighten where exactly this RNG was drawing from, perhaps best I wait for the Fallout4 GECK to come out in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Save Before talking to the Dr after delivering h2h0 what ever his name is. after talking the doctor he'll give you new mission, now go talk to pam. she'll give you random locations that you haven't discover yet. if you don't like location reload from that point. It should always almost give you new random locations. From my memory you can actually get Sanctuary as a base too if you didn't go there Like I didn't.